# How to use aggregation functions with multiple joins?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find max work experience of employee `Milo`. Here is my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE company (
  id   INT          NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE employee (
  id   INT          NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE company_employee (
  company_id  INT NOT NULL,
  employee_id INT NOT NULL,
  hire_date   DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  resign_date DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES company (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employee (id)
);
```

And my query which gets all companies of Milo

```
SELECT
  employee.name, company.name, company_employee.hire_date, 
  company_employee.resign_date, 
  (company_employee.resign_date - company_employee.hire_date)   
FROM company
  JOIN company_employee
    ON (company.id = company_employee.company_id)
  JOIN employee
    ON (company_employee.employee_id = employee.id)
  WHERE employee.name = 'Milo'
```

It returns

```
+------+--------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
| name | company_name | hire_date | resign_date | experience_days | 
+------+--------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
| Milo | IBM          |1997-04-17 | 1998-03-08  | 325             | 
| Milo | IBM          |2012-04-03 | 2014-02-15  | 683             |
| Milo | IBM          |2000-08-10 | 2003-01-01  | 874             |
+------+--------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
```

But I need only one record with max experience

```
+------+-----+------------+------------+-----+
| Milo | IBM | 2000-08-10 | 2003-01-01 | 874 |
+------+-----+------------+------------+-----+
```

UPD:

This query finds amount of all employees of each company

```
SELECT
  company.name,
  COUNT(company_employee.employee_id)
FROM company
  LEFT JOIN company_employee
    ON company.id = company_employee.company_id
GROUP BY company.name
HAVING COUNT(company_employee.employee_id) > 0;
```

Can I simplified it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need aggregation function (`MAX`), because you are not aggregating here anything.

You can just add `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses, like:

```
ORDER BY experience_days DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The whole query could be probably:

```
SELECT
  employee.name, company.name, company_employee.hire_date, 
  company_employee.resign_date, 
  (company_employee.resign_date - company_employee.hire_date)  as experience_days
FROM company
  JOIN company_employee
    ON (company.id = company_employee.company_id)
  JOIN employee
    ON (company_employee.employee_id = employee.id)
  WHERE employee.name = 'Milo'   
ORDER BY experience_days DESC
LIMIT 1
```

@update

Yes you can simplify your query.

First of all, you can use `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` as you're looking for companies with employees.

Then, because you will already get  only companies with employees (employee row must exist to be joined with company), you don't need to use `HAVING` condition.

```
SELECT
  company.name,
  COUNT(company_employee.employee_id)
FROM company
  JOIN company_employee
    ON company.id = company_employee.company_id
GROUP BY company.name;
```

Comment: How can I use SUM function in my tables. Any examples?

Comment: `SUM()` is an aggregation function too, What do you want to sum?

Comment: If I need to output all companies and find amount of employees for all companies, what query I should write?

Comment: Sorry, I mean `COUNT()`, not `SUM()` function.

Comment: Select companies, join employees, and group by company and use `COUNT` to get amount of employees in this company

Comment: Please see my updated question. Is it possible to simplify my last query?